# How to avoid 404 on Consul Config Watch for Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, consul, spring-cloud-consul

I'm configuring consul config on my Spring Boot app. But after release it to production I begin to get some 404's with some consul headers:

My bootstrap.yml relevant keys:

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: myapp
  profiles:
    active: local
  main.allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
    discovery:
      enabled: false
    consul:
      host: https://consul.mycompany.com.br
      port: 443
      config:
        enabled: true
        prefix: product-confs/myteam
        default-context: ${spring.application.name}/raw/feature-flags
        profile-separator: /
```

On server, the relevant key structure is:

```
└── raw
    ├── feature-flags
    │   ├── docker
    │   │   ├── BACKGROUND_COLOR
    │   │   └── NAVBAR
    │   ├── qa
    │   │   ├── BACKGROUND_COLOR
    │   │   └── NAVBAR
    │   └── sit
    │       ├── BACKGROUND_COLOR
    │       ├── FILTROS_VENDA_APENAS_CONJUNTO
    │       └── NAVBAR
    └── static
        ├── docker
        │   ├── config.json
        │   └── config.xml
        ├── qa
        │   ├── config.json
        │   └── config.xml
        └── sit
            ├── config.json
            └── config.xml
```

With this configuration the application read FILTROS_VENDA_APENAS_CONJUNTO ok, but config watch keep getting 404.

I tried change keys `spring.cloud.consul.config.prefix`, `spring.cloud.consul.config.default-context` and `spring.cloud.consul.config.profile-separator`, without success. Although when I disable config watch with `spring.cloud.consul.config.watch.enabled: false` all 404's go away.

What else can it be?

Comment: Did it work in the test environment?

Comment: It read the config I need. The problem is it make a lot of 404 requests, in any environment.